# Go "&^" operator, what does it mean?

Tags: python, go, operators, bit-manipulation

I am struggling to understand what the [`&^` and `&^=` operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators) mean in Go. I cannot find an answer either in the documentation (which states it's a bit clear operator, but it does not help me much) or by trials.

In particular, I want to know if there is an equivalent in Python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are the ["AND NOT" or "bit clear" operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432398/difference-between-some-operators-golang), "useful" for [clearing those bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23192262/how-would-you-set-and-clear-a-single-bit-in-go) of the left-hand side operand that are set in right-side operand.

I put the "useful" in quotes since all other languages that derive the bitwise operations from C one does this with bitwise AND `&` and bitwise NOT `~`; thus `5 &^ 2` would be just `5 & ~2` in Python; and `a &^= 3` of Go would be `a &= ~3` in Python.